# ¿Qué etiqueta en css debo poner o modificar para hacer más delgados los textfield?

Tags: css, reactjs

```css
.containerbox{
    display:flex;
    margin: auto;
    align-items: center;
    width: 900px;
    margin-right: 150px;
}

.text{
   background-color: white;
   width: 500px;
}
```

Adjunto imagen de la parte que quiero darle estilos

[image: solo quiero hacer los textfields mas delgados que estilo o que propiedad darle]

```
<TextField onChange={(e) =>{
    setClabe(e.target.value);
    console.log(Clabeinterbancaria.length);
    if(Clabeinterbancaria.length>=18){
        setErrorClabe(true);
        setleyenda("la clabe no debe de contener mas de 18 caracteres");
    }else{
        setErrorClabe(false);
        setleyenda("");
    }
}} type="usuario" id="Clave" name="clave" placeholder='0000 0000 0000 0000' error={errorClabe}  helperText={Leyenda} variant="filled" className='text'></TextField>
```

Este es uno de mis textfields no se si aqui tenga que poner el high para hacerlos mas bajos.

Comment: y como está estructurado el html? con delgados te refieres menos anchos? o menos altos?

Comment: menos altos asi de ancho esta bien solo los quiero hacer mas bajos

Comment: revisa si tienes aplicado algun margin, algun padding o algun line-height a los inputs

Comment: no tengo nada de eso agregado

Comment: solo el margin para moverlos en conjunto

Comment: así sin ver el html pues no se bien, pero probaste a ponerle height al textfield?

Comment: ya pero no reconoce el textfield

Comment: por favor, pon el código html del formulario. si no va a ser dificil....

Comment: Ese es un texfield de Material UI u otra librería. Si es el de material, por defecto añade padding de 9px a todos los inputs. Normalmente pasandole la propiedad `inputProps={{style:{padding:0}}}` suele funcionar

Comment: es de material ui

Comment: pues con lo que te puse te debería de funcionar

Comment: a ok eso lo pongo directo en el textfield o como propiedad en el css

Comment: si funciono gracia

Comment: De nada. dentro del style que te puse, puedes poner tambien el height y otras propiedades css y te funcionaría

Comment: y para darle color al formhelptext?

Comment: Añadir las propiedades al textfield `helperText={"helperText"} FormHelperTextProps={{style:{color:"yellow"}}}`

Answer (score 0):

con el atributo `height` por ejemplo:

```
.text{
     background-color: white; 
     width: 500px;
     height: 20px;
}
```

Si no te funciona te sugiero que abras la consola del navegador y compruebes que no te está heredando nada de otro elemento superior. Si es así, puedes intentar arreglarlo o sino... meter esta linea, pero no es una buena práctica normalmente:

```
.text{
     background-color: white; 
     width: 500px;
     height: 20px !important;
}
```